# tinymce replaces hashtag '#' with h1 on newline

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm having a problem with what seems to be a feature of tinymce (but I can't find documentation on it). When I type '#foo', follow by a newline it creates a h1 with the text 'foo'.
I discovered that when I use 2 hashtags it creates an h2, 3 hashtags and h3, ...

The problem is I'm using keywords like '#foo#' to be replaced by certain values, and now these are getting replaced by h1 accidentally.

Anyone got a clue on how I can stop tinymce from doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by the **textpattern** plugin. It uses markdown like settings to make editing easier. You can disable this plugin or reconfigure it.

Check this page for the options
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:textpattern_patterns

Comment: So, that was really easy. I guess the textpattern plugin was enabled in the standard config I copied when implementing TinyMCE. Thank you!